# Callout inconsistency between Postman and Salesforce

Tags: callout

I've got a callout that I'm doing that is receiving an HTML response.

I've got this correctly rendering on my Visualforce Page via an outputText.  However, I am not getting the right Body back.

When I use the same setup in Postman (POST, endpoint, parameters), I get the expected response which is essentially a system's home page.  However, when I do the same details within my HTTP response in Apex I am presented with the Login page.  When I look at the debug log, that is the HTML body that is being returned.

Why would Salesforce be getting a different response from something like Postman?

Comment: Look at the headers of the http request that your POSTMAN is setting for the callout .I assume you are setting wrongly for apex callout

Comment: Looking to try and find a delta.  Not finding one just yet... :(